# No commuting diagrams in a free category?

Tags: category-theory

Is it correct that given a diagram $D$, that in the free category on $D$ there are no commuting diagrams consisting solely of morphisms that are also in $D$, and that don’t have identity morphisms in them?

Comment: no, for example $f1_A=1_Bf$ for any $f\colon A\to B$

Comment: @RyleeLyman edited.

Comment: Also for any composable $f$ and $g$, we have a commutative triangle with edges $f$, $g$, and $f\circ g$.

Comment: What do you mean by "a free category"? Usually we talk about *the* free category *on* some directed graph or other kind of object.

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes you’re right, my question was imprecise. Also, I’m asking this question as a sanity check whether I understand what a free category is.

Comment: The correct intuition is that "the only commutative diagrams are those which are forced to exist by the category axioms".

Comment: Categories modeling $\lambda$-calculi can be seen as freely generated and still they have commuting diagrams for exponentionals, possibly products etc

Comment: @frabala Indeed: more generally, the free category with such and such structure (when such a thing makes sense) will have exactly the commutative diagrams which are forced to exist by the axioms of categories with such and such structure.

Answer (score 5):

No.  For instance, the empty diagram commutes in any category!  So does a diagram $A\to B$ with just a single morphism (between different vertices).  Or, you could have a diagram like $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> B\\
@V{f}VV @VV{g}V \\
B @>{g}>> C
\end{CD}$$
which commutes because some of its arrows happen to be labelled with the same morphism.

You could probably come up with some combinatorial condition that will guarantee that a diagram doesn't commute, but I think it's much more fruitful to just understand the explicit characterization of morphisms in the free category.  Namely, if $D$ is a directed graph and $F$ is the free category on $D$, then a morphism in $F$ between two vertices $x,y$ of $D$ is just a directed path in $D$ from $x$ to $y$, and composition of morphisms is concatenation of paths.  So, for instance, a composition of two edges of $D$ can never equal another edge of $D$, since the composition is a path of length $2$.